# Add Chromecast in a Maven project

Tags: android, maven, chromecast

I've been struggling with no luck the past few days to add Chromecast in my Android project, which is built with Maven.

Similarly to as if it were an ANT project, I'm adding the android-support-v7-mediarouter as a library. I do this by adding the following dependency in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>android.support</groupId>
    <artifactId>compatibility-v7-mediarouter</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

The error that I get when I try to build the project is:

```
No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton'
```

which I think is quite obvious since the android-support-v7-mediarouter library does not have a reference to android-support-v7-appcompat.

So, my question is; how do I solve that? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Android, with Android Studio is moving to Gradle http://www.gradle.org/, you might wish to check that out.  All the AppCompat libraries work with it.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Has this been solved for you and how. If solved, please write that as an answer and I will give you a point. Furthermore you could check that as the correct answer.

Comment: hey @javabeangrinder, I just posted my solution. Check out the answer bellow and if you have any further questions, shout 'em. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I solved it:

First, I created a POM file (without any dependencies) for the **android-support-v7-appcompat** library and uploaded the library to my repository.

Then, I created a POM file for the **android-support-v7-mediarouter** library, adding **android-support-v7-appcompat** as a dependency (both the apklib and the jar) and uploaded this library to my repository, too.

In my case, I chose to use the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android). This library has two dependencies; **android-support-v7-mediarouter** and **google-play-services**. Thus, the next step was to create a POM for **google-play-services** and upload the library to my repository, too. Then, I added a POM to the **CastCompanionLibrary** where I declared its two dependencies  (both the apklibs and the jar files).

Finally, in my project's POM, I added the **CastCompanionLibrary** as a dependency (just the apklib) and... voila! If you choose to not use the CastCompanionLibrary, then you can simply add **android-support-v7-mediarouter** and **google-play-services** as dependencies to your project's POM.

Also, make sure to exclude any existing duplicates when you add the dependencies. For instance, some of the rest of the declared dependencies in my project had a dependency on an older version of **android-support-v7-appcompat**, which I had to exclude from all of them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great work Giorgos! Thanks for the post.
Have you succeeded in using only mediarouter+appcompat in any project?

Comment: Did you convert to Gradle also since the CastCompanionLibrary is aimed for that?

Comment: No, I haven't converted it to Gradle. The CastCompanionLibrary works fine for Maven, too, just by adding the appropriate POM file. 

Regarding your first question, I haven't used mediarouter in any other project except for the one I described above. But the way you should go, would be similar to how I used it for the CastCompanionLibrary. And that would be adding appcompat as a dependency to the mediarouter library and then add mediarouter as a dependency to your project.

Comment: Since mediarouter already depends on appcompat, if you add then both as dependencies to your project, you'll end up having a duplicate of appcompat.

Comment: That sounded a bit strange to me but I tried it nevertheless, however to no avail. My project has dependencies to the appcompat as well as mediarouter and it now lacks resources. I built the mediarouter apklib and jar using the maven-android-sdk-deployer and the pom there clearly has a dependency to appcompat. Please, more suggestions. :)

Comment: I built the libraries with maven-android-sdk-deployer as well and it took me some time to realise that it was not uploading the POM files in my repository, automatically. I had to explicitly set it to do so. So, first check if the right POM files exist in your repository for each of the libraries that you upload with the deployer. In my case there was no POM for the mediarouter, thus when I added it in my project and excluded appcompat from the rest of the libraries that depended on it, my project was complaining for missing resources. You might be running on the same issue.

Comment: How did you explicitly set it to do so?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If I remember correctly, what happened was that the deployer was not including the POM file automatically, in the apklib that it created. In order to fix that, in every library that I wanted to convert to apklib using the deployer, I had to add `<pomFile>pom.xml</pomFile>` under the `<configuration>` tag, in the POM of this library. This way, the POM was added in the apklib and all the dependencies of this library were included.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to set things up in maven but one thing to keep in mind is that the android-support-v7-mediarouter library has dependency on the appcompat support library and to use these in your own project, both of them should be set up as library projects (i.e. you cannnt just add the jars for these libraries to your own project). I am not sure if this information is of use to you regarding your maven set up but just thought I would mention that in case it does.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but adding both the jar and apklib for the both libs does not correct the problem stated above. As far as I have come it seems to be a compile time issue when compiling the mediarouter which at that state cant find the resources from the appcompat lib.
Do you have any other suggestions?